# How do I get an Access 2010 database to work with .NET 2

Tags: .net, database, ms-access

I have an ASP.NET application developed with VS 2012 that uses an Access 2010 accdb database. With a .NET 4 target framework, this works fine but my target needs to be .NET 2. When I build with this, I can read and write from the database using OleDb commands but when I get to a page with an AccessDataSource on it, I get:

> OleDbException (0x80004005): Unrecognized database format 'C:\Users\Paul\Google Drive\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\BoxOffice\BoxOffice\BoxOffice.accdb'.

The same thing happens if I use framework 3 or 3.5. My target CPU is AnyCPU (I've also tried X86).

My connection string is:

> connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\Users\Paul\Google Drive\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\BoxOffice\BoxOffice\BoxOffice.accdb""

I have looked for solutions to this, but in these the 'Unrecognised database format' error relates to problems with the database or connection string, and as I can read and write to it, that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Paul

Answer (score 1):

One of the two following patches should solve this issue:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734

Regards